# YouTube explicit authorisation to playback video

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Building a local application which allows the embedding of YouTube videos through their standard iframe api. However, I am facing an issue where the video(s) have a domains blacklist in YouTube and although my application runs locally the videos don't play with the message

> This video contains content from XXX. It is restricted from playback
>   on certain sites.

However, I want the video(s) to be playable in my application but not on the domains I have added in YouTube blacklist.

Is there a way for my application to authorise itself to play my videos but without loosing the black listed domains?

The block embedding content has no option to allow `file:///` as a playback location so I am hoping for a programmatic way around it.

Thanks in advance,

George

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am building a mobile application with Ionic Framework. I heard by setting origin as one of the playervar could work, but I haven't given it a try yet. Have you figured out other solutions?

Comment: Never got around it. Still no luck.